# reloadSection leads to error "attempt to delete section 1, but there are only 1 sections before the update with userInfo"

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, uikit, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am getting an error "attempt to delete section 1, but there are only 1 sections before the update with userInfo" that is apparently caused by a call to `reloadSections:withRowAnimation:`. How can this happen, as a reload is not a delete, or is it in part?

This occurs when rolling back changes in a `UITableViewController` whose data source is partly backed by a `UIFetchedResultsController` (the table's 1st section contains a constant row; its remaining sections correspond to the `UIFetchedResultController`'s sections: in this case there are two such sections with one row each. The `UITableViewController` also acts as the `UIFetchedResultsController`'s delegate.

During a rollback (to cancel deletion of the last two sections), the delegate receives the following calls:

1. `controllerWillChangeContent:`; `numberOfSectionsInTableView` is 1; delegate calls `beginUpdates`
2. `controller:didChangeSection:atIndex:forChangeType:` announces `NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert` for section 1; numberOfSectionsInTableView`is 3; delegate calls`insertSections:withRowAnimation:`for section 2,`reloadSections:withRowAnimation:` for section 1
3. `controller:didChangeSection:atIndex:forChangeType:` announces `NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert` for section 0; delegate calls `insertSections:withRowAnimation:` for section 1, `reloadSections:withRowAnimation:` for section 0
4. `controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:` announces `NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert` for `indexPath` (1,0); delegate calls `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` for `indexPath` (2,0)
5. `controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:` announces `NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert` for `indexPath` (0,0); delegate calls `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` for `indexPath` (1,0)
6. `controllerDidChangeContent:`; delegate calls `endUpates`, which results in this error:

> attempt to delete section 1, but there are only 1 sections before the
>   update with userInfo

If the delegate does not call `reloadSections:withRowAnimation` as indicated, the error does not occur.

What causes the error in this specific situation and how can I prevent it? (BTW, reloads are necessary in this case for updating titles for headers and footers in adjacent sections.)

**UPDATE** I seems that the problem may be related to the fact that `numberOfSectionsInTableView` jumps back from 1 to 3 (as a result of [`rollback`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/rollback)) in one step after `controllerWillChangeContent:` whereas the number of actual sections (and rows) grows incrementally inside the "bracket" between `controllerWillChangeContent:` and `controllerDidChangeContent:`. But isn't the bracketing exactly meant to allow temporary differences between the number of items in the data source vs. the table? My `numberOfSectionInTableView:` is defined as follows:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView: (UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1 + self.fetchedResultsController.sections.count;
}
```